# How to restrict objects private data member modification in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, private, members

please check the below code, i need a solution to restrict the modification of private data members of class A. please suggest.

```
class A{
private:
    int a;
    int b;

public:
    A(int i=0, int j=0):a(i),b(j){
        cout<<"A's constructor runs"<<endl;
    }
    void showVal(){
        cout<<"a: "<<a<<" b: "<<b<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    A ob1(10,20);
    ob1.showVal();

    int *ptr = (int*)&ob1;
    *(ptr+0)=1;
    *(ptr+1)=2;

    ob1.showVal();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no problem here. The program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: You cannot just assume offsets like that to access a member variable. There are [ways to determine the offsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180842/how-to-calculate-offset-of-a-class-member-at-compile-time) but you cannot simply assume a value due to padding, vtables, etc. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378271/what-does-an-object-look-like-in-memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that you can do to prevent someone 'warping' pointers like that. You cannot prevent your `private` data from being deliberately or maliciously modified, only accidentally modified by users of your class.

Unless of course you manage to get your data stored into read-only memory... You could get some memory from the OS, put your data into it, then get the OS to mark the memory as read-only - and only then 'publish' the pointer to your data. Of course, you can't modify your data either...

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample is less about *modification* of private data members than it's about outright *corruption* of an object via a rogue pointer. I don't think there's a practical way in C++ to prevent crazy or evil programmers from doing just that.

`private` aims to protect sane clients from accidentally breaking the internal state of your object. Those who don't wish to play nice can simply do `#define private public` anyway.

I'm reminded of a quote by [Herb Sutter](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-90-solution-factories/), which is related to a different topic but I think it addresses your problem pretty well:

> Remember, our concern is to protect against Murphy, not Machiavelli—against bugs and mistakes, not deliberate crimes—and such pathological abuses fall into the latter category.