# Is there a way to access C struct memory directly from JS using WASM?

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly

I have the following C struct

```
typedef struct {
    ValueType type;
    union {
        bool boolean;
        double number;
        Obj* obj;
    } as;
} Value;
```

where `ValueType` is an enum as follows

```
typedef enum {
    VALUE_BOOL,
    VALUE_NIL,
    VALUE_NUMBER,
    VALUE_OBJ
} ValueType;
```

Using WASM, I define an external JS file called `js_library.js` within which is a function called accessStruct with the following signature defined in C.

```
extern void accessStruct(Value value);
```

I implement the function in JS as follows

```
function accessStruct(value) {
  console.log(Module.getValue(value, "i32"));
}
```

I can accurately log the value of the `ValueType` field as an integer. However, I was under the impression that if I simply increment the pointer by the required offset, I could access the remaining struct fields since they need to be laid out next to each other in memory, in the order specified.

So, I tried

```
function accessStruct(value) {
  console.log(Module.getValue(value, "i32"));
  const v = value + 32;
  console.log(Module.getValue(v, "i64"));
}
```

`ValueType` occupies 4 bytes = 32 bits. If the `ValueType` is a double, I should be able to access the double value through the `Module.getValue(v, "i64");` line of code but I get garbage back.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do you think a `double` looks like when you pretend it's an `i64`?

Comment: if you write something like `union {int64_t i; double d;}; d = 1234.5678;`  and then print `i` you get garbage, don't you?

Comment: @user253751 - I understood `i32` & `i64` to respectively refer to memory that occupies 32 bits and 64 bits. So, in C `ints` occupy 4 bytes and `doubles` occupy 8 bytes. Which is why I used `i64` to decode the double.

Regarding your second comment, I thought unions occupy the same space in memory. The only thing that needs to change is how many bytes I read starting at the beginning of the union to read diff data types, no?

Comment: Both i64 and double contain 64 bits, but the bits mean different things

Answer (score 0):

The [getValue function](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#access-memory-from-javascript) expects its first argument to be the offset **in bytes**. The second argument is the data type. You need "double" in this case, as per the documentation.

The `const v = value + 32;` seems to be in bits, but you need bytes. To get the offset of a field from the start of the structure (in bytes) use something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180842/how-to-calculate-offset-of-a-class-member-at-compile-time). You have to probably write some function in the C++ side to return you the offset and then in the JavaScript side do:

```
function accessStruct(offset) {
  console.log(Module.getValue(offset, "i32"));
  console.log(Module.getValue(offset + offsetToValue(), "double"));
}
```

You have to also ensure that the memory addressing is 32 bits. It seems that you can use "*" instead of "i32", as per the documentation, to support the 64 bits of memory addressing. Maybe you can also use a pointer to the instance as well: `extern void accessStruct(Value * value);`

Comment: Passing a struct to JS, decays that struct into an int value which is a pointer to the beginning of the struct. So, I'm not sure what difference it would make to pass the pointer, except having to call `getValue` twice in succession.

As for the offset, if it is in bytes, adding 1 to the value should then give me the double value since the space occupied by the ValueType enum is 1 byte but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Its more probable that the double is aligned to 8 bytes. The pointer you currently have shall be to a temporal copy of the struct, not to the original struct.