# What &class_type::member_field means in c++?

Tags: c++

I was looking for a way to get the offset of a class field and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20141143/14525250).

I still can't figure out how these expressions work:

```cpp
offsetOf(&X::c)
```

and

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U> constexpr size_t offsetOf(U T::*member)
```

What do `&X::c` and `U T::*member` mean in this context?

Comment: Why not just use the standard `offsetof()` instead?  `offsetof(X, c)`

Comment: but `c` isn't a function

Comment: I'll add dupes for data members, too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i didn't know about offsetof - that's why i was looking for answer here and found this. Anyway thank you

Comment: @Smok1e https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof