# C++ nested classes

Tags: c++, nested-class

I have searched through some SO articles but haven't found anything (yet) that quite addresses my question. Apologies if this answer does already exist somewhere.

A bit of background first...

I want to represent a device with "sections" of functionality, where the functionality has a hierarchical tree-like structure. Rather than have a load of flattened functions like

```
DeviceReferenceCheck(), 
DeviceRefereceSet(), 
DevicePhaseSetX(), 
DevicePhaseDefaultsSet...()
```

I'd instead like to leverage nested classes so I could get

```
dev.reference.check()
dev.reference.set()
dev.phase.setx()
dev.phase.defaults.set...()
```

To do this I'm trying to use nested classes to get the `obj.func.subfunction.subsub....()` structure. The nested classes need a reference to the outermost class because they need to use read/write functions provided there.

In my attempts, the first thing I don't understand very well is as follows... I had tried this myself but then stopped using it because of a compiler warning.

```
class GPIBDevice_Agilent53132A : public GPIBDevice
{
private:
    class RefOsc {
    public:
        // ... snip ...
        RefOsc(GPIBDevice_Agilent53132A &parent);
        // ... snip ...
    } ro;
public:
   // ... snip ...
   GPIBDevice_Agilent53132A();
   // ... snip ...
};

GPIBDevice_Agilent53132A::GPIBDevice_Agilent53132A() : GPIBDevice(), ro(*this)
{
}
```

Compiler says: `gpibdevice_agilent53132a.cpp(5): warning C4355: 'this' : used in base member initializer list`.

Aha, I think to myself... clever compiler... using `this` in the initialiser list is probably not a good idea because the class hasn't been fully constructed yet.

**Question 1:**
Is what I've said above correct? Is using `this`, in the enclosing class' initialiser list, to give the nested class a reference to the enclosing class, a bad idea? My thoughts are "yes" but would like some clarification because in other SO threads I have seen this method being used ([Nested Class member function can't access function of enclosing class. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058267/nested-class-member-function-cant-access-function-of-enclosing-class-why)).

My approach to get around this was to have a member pointer to nested and then when actually in the constructor (so now safe to use this as class has been constructed) made a new inner class where I could pass in the reference to *this without warnings. Is this the standard way of doing it?

Continuing on....

The reason for the private nested class is btw that I don't want the user to be able to instantiate that class him/herself. Now, I did have it public to begin with... tried to use a private constructor in the nested class, but then the compiler told me it couldn't construct the class. So presumably the enclosing class can see nested class private data members?

**Question 2:** 
Why can't the enclosing class see the nested classes private data members/functions?

My work around for this is to have the nested class declare the enclosing class as a friend. Is this really necessary?

Thanks for you help guys!

Comment: Using 'this' in initializer list is not a good idea because if you access the members of the class that are not constructed yet, your program may crash. Having said that, if you are just storing a pointer for future use, you won't have any issues.

Comment: If the base class ctor only stores the reference, it's safe. In that case I wouldn't call it a bad idea straight away, but I would look at the design carefully because it might be a sign of something else gone wrong.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. My approach to get around this was to have a member pointer to nested and then when actually in the constructor (so now safe to use this as class has been constructed) made a `new` inner class where I could pass in the reference to `*this` without warnings. Is this the standard way of doing it? How come in the other SO thread I mentioned is the former method used?

Comment: Is there a reason why RefOsc is a class at all. You don't store pointers to it isn't a pimpl. Simply make everything part of GPIBDevice_Agilent53132A.

Comment: @Jan: Thanks for taking the time to look at my question but please refer back to it for reason... also I should mention the nested class needs to use it's parents read/write functions (I shall update question with that)

Comment: @Jimbo yes I read this, but in my opinion you are building a lot of classes which are heighly coupled and not usefull alone. All for a little bit of syntactic shugar. But if you want to split this you could try to use something like CRTP for implementation. So you would save the refernce to this. But could it be that your understanding of nested classes comes from a java background?

Comment: @Jan, Yes true... it is really just syntactic sugar, but I really like it :) The class coupling is, as you point out, very tight indeed, but in this instance because they all relate to the one device, perhaps not sure a worry. I'm reasing up about CRTP as I've not used/seen it before. Thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: @Jan, Yes I think I was thinking in terms of Java nesting... doh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary**

Thanks to [***Jan***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1918154/jan-herrmann) for his explanation of the [***curiously recurring template pattern***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). It's an interesting method to know about.

I've ended up accepting my own answer because I feel it answers the questions directly. The CRTP method is good but doesn't directly answer questions 1 & 2, but does provide a good alternative.

**Question 1:**

It would seem that this is possible. Thank you to [***mkirci***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2047933/mkirci) and [***R. Martinho Fernandes***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes) for confirming my suspicions on why the compiler generated the warning and whether it was "safe" to ignore it.

In summary... not the best idea to use `this` in the initialiser list of the constructor because the class has not yet been constructed. As the guys point out, this can cause UB if the pointer is used. I've decided to use my work around which is use a pointer to the inner class, and then create it once inside the outer-class constructor... this way outer class is already created and can pass a reference to itself to the inner class safely.

**Question 2:**

From the C++ standard, I have found (after a lot of digging) in section 11.7:

> > A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member. The members of an enclosing class have no special access to members of a nested class; the usual access rules (Clause 11) shall be obeyed.

The standard gave the following example:

```
class E {
    int x;
    class B { };
    class I {
        B b; // OK: E::I can access E::B
        int y;
        void f(E* p, int i) {
            p->x = i; // OK: E::I can access E::x
        }
    };

    int g(I* p) {
        return p->y; // error: I::y is private
    }
};
```

So, this is (annoyingly) why my outer class cannot call the inner class' private constructor. My solution has been to make the outer class a friend of the inner class. I.e in the above example add `friend E;` into the inner class decl.