# Access Protected Members of a enclosing class [Nested Classes]

Tags: c++, class, nested, protected

I got the following code:

```
class enclosing{
protected:
    int var1 = 2;
    int var2 = 4;
public:
    class problem{
    friend enclosing;
    public:
        void DoStuff(enclosing&e1){
            int Sum = e1.var1 + e1.var2;
        }
    }i1;
}e1;
```

My question is, how do i access the protected member variables of the enclosing class?

Is this even Legal?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058267/nested-class-member-function-cant-access-function-of-enclosing-class-why?rq=1

Comment: No it's not. You need to provide the inner class an instance of an enclosing class to work on.

Comment: so i should add a "friend" ?

Comment: Maybe, you want to pass `e1` to `problem::DoStuff`?

Comment: Maybe. But how would i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your friendship backwards - a class can't declare itself to be friend of somebody else.

Unlike in Java's "inner classes", a class defined within a class does not automatically have access to an instance of the class the defines it - the "inner" class is completely independent, and you need to pass it the instance you want it to work with.

Like so:

```
class enclosing
{
protected:
    int var1 = 2;
    int var2 = 4;
public:
    friend class problem;
    class problem
    {
    public:
        void DoStuff(enclosing& e){
            int Sum = e.var1 + e.var2;
        }
    } i1;
} e1;

int main()
{
    e1.i1.DoStuff(e1);
    enclosing e2;
    e2.i1.DoStuff(e1); // Also works
    enclosing::problem x;
    x.DoStuff(e2); // This, too.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination

Answer (score 0):

The data members have to be accessed via an object of the enclosing class. For example

```
void DoStuff( const enclosing &e){
            int Sum = e.var1 + e.var2;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks man, you made my day. Finally a good solution after searching for an hour